# How can we execute single test on multiple browser using browserstack and Geb Framework

Tags: testing, groovy, geb

I am using Geb framework to execute the testcases on browserstack.Currently I am able to execute my test on single browser(Say Firefox) on browserstack.I need to run the same test on multiple browser

Comment: so what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'Gradle geb-browserstack Plugin' to run your tests on multiple browsers on BrowserStack. More details available [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/cloud-browsers.html#gradle_geb_browserstack_plugin).

Using this plugin, the capabilities are passed as follows:

*browserName_platform_browser-version*

For example, to run tests on Firefox 32 on MAC, the capabilities are:

*firefox_mac_32*

If you have any BrowserStack related queries, you can always get in touch with them at support@browserstack.com

**EDIT**:
I have created a sample project [here](https://github.com/UmangSardesai/geb-concurrent-example-gradle), that can help you get started with running Geb Tests in parallel on multiple browsers on BrowserStack.